# SSIS 2012 & Excel 2010 provider issue

Tags: ssis

### I am using windows 7 64 bit,VS 2010 and MS Office 2010. Trying to build an ssis pkg using an excel source, the problem arises as below.

Could not retrieve the table information for the connection manager 'Excel Connection Manager'.

### Failed to connect to the source using the connection manager 'Excel Connection Manager'

I found some solutions on internet, tried these steps by 
1) installing the MS access database engine 2010 redistributable_x64.exe. I restarted the system, But still the problem persists. i couldnt find the provider in the list of providers in the oledb source and so selected the jet 4.0 oledb provider and changed the extended properties to Excel 12.0, then i get the following error:

---

### Test connection failed because of an error in initializing provider. Could not find installable ISAM.

and also if i use excel source, its throwing me an error as given above on the top.

2) Also, changed the run 64bit runtime to false and also back to True again.
3) tried to change the platform of the project , but it is disabled.

Could yopu please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the 32 bits provider.

Even though your windows is 64 bits, the SSDT development environment is a 32-bit environment. The reason why you cant find the provider in the list of providers is because it only shows 32-bit data providers. You can only see 64-bit providers that have a 32-bit version available on the development machine.

Answer (score 0):

Though its bit late but might to very helpful for other guys.

Visual Studio 2010/2012 comes with 32-bit version only and hence it cannot use ACE OLEDB 64-bit version, which comes with installation of office 2010 64-bit version.

So the solution here would be uninstall 64-bit version office 2010 and install it's 32-bit version. Re-try to add the excel connection manager.

This has resolved my issue and hope for other guys as well.